# FPDF page break in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using PHP and FPDF to generate a PDF with a list of items. My problem is, item does not                goes to a second or third page.

I want to print next block of  data in 2nd page of pdf.
     Someone please help me. I have used `setautopage break()`   but not working.  
 PLEASE HELP!

```
       <?php

        require('fpdf.php');

        class PDF extends FPDF {

            function Header() { 

                $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
                $this->Rect(50,30,100,30,'F');
                $this->Text(80,45,"3D");
                $this->SetXY(20,20);
                $this->Cell(30,10,'A',1,0,'L');             
                $this->SetXY(80,20);
                $this->Cell(30,10,'B',1,0,'L');                                         
                $this->SetXY(80,60);
                $this->Cell(30,10,'C',1,1,'L');             
                $this->SetXY(150,60);
                $this->Cell(30,10,'D',1,1,'L');             
            }   

            function Footer() {
                $this->SetY(-12);
                $this->Cell(169,20,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');   
            }

            $pdf=new PDF();
            $pdf->AddPage(); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: where is your list of items? can you provide some code?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use [GetY](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/gety.htm) and [Addpage](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm) for this purpose.

`Use GetY to get the current position, subtract it from the height of your document. If that is less than 6x (you have 6 rows) your multicell height, then force a page break by using AddPage.`

See a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349827/fpdf-page-break-issue)